# Excel Information from sheet 1 to automatically filter to multiple other sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, report

I run a report and export to Excel.  Each "guy" has information on this Sheet.  What I want to do is make a formula for 10 other tabs that essentially says "if Column `B` has this name in it, pull the entire row of information to this Sheet".  And I need to do that with each Sheet, each with a different guy.

Comment: Did you take a look at `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: I tried a vlookup, but I am not sure how to do the formula to pull the entire row of information if just one column reads a certain  name.

Comment: @SarahKS You need `VLOOKUP` - I'd suggest doing some more googling. All you need to do is have a `VLOOKUP` formuila in each cell in the row that references the cell in Column B.

Comment: VLOOKUP is at best a sub optimal solution, and at worst no solution at all in this particular case. See my comment below.

Comment: @Jeeped: I wouldn't say that the other question is a duplicate: that question asks for assistance to a VBA approach, this one asks for guidance on a formula approach. (Although of course you can use VBA, Pivot, Formulas, or even PowerQuery to answer either)

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP` sounds like your best option. `INDEX-MATCH` may also work.

You want to check out nesting `IF`, `ISNUMBER`, and `SEARCH/FIND` together, that may help you considerably.

Comment: A VLOOKUP approach only works if you have one record per person. And given multiple columns are involved, an INDEX/MATCH will be x times more efficient, where x is the number of columns involved.

Comment: Good point. I didn’t consider the limitations of ‘VLOOKUP’

Comment: I have actually never used the search/find option..  Not even sure how to go about it.  This seems like the easiest thing that I swear I have done in the past so it's getting frustrating to not get it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use a PivotTable. Turn your source list into an Excel Table using the Table icon from the Insert tab (or simply select a cell in your data and use the CTRL + T shortcut). Then make a PivotTable out of it, put the name in the Page area, and whatever other columns you want in the ROWS area. Turn off Subtotals and change layout to Tabular in the Design tab, then copy your worksheet as many times as you have names. Then filter each PivotTable to only show individual names.

Even better, create the first PivotTable, then use the Show Pagefields functionality to automatically create new sheets each with a version of the PivotTable automatically filtered on each name. (Analyze>Options>Show Report Filter Pages). Check out YouTube for examples of both PivotTables in general and the Show Report Filter Pages magic trick in particular...look for videos from Mike Girven (ExcelIsFun) or Debra Dalgleish (Contextures) or Bill Jelen (Mr Excel) for starters.

PivotTables may seem daunting at first, but they are easy to master, and turn you into an Excel ninja.

Comment: I like the pivot table idea... hadn't thought of that.  now I am working on trying to figure out how to get it to only pull the rows of information for each individual guy when I add columns of information.. sheesh.. apparently its been a while since I did all this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that requirement? I don't quite follow, but I'm sure I can help you do this easily enough. PivotTables are the Swiss Army Knife that every Excel analyst should have clipped to their belt :-)

Comment: Can you mark my response as the answer if it satisfactorily resolves your question?